# Button click handler for second layout

Tags: android

In my program main and output are two layouts. First main layout is shown to user and it allows user to enter some data and when a button is pressed it fetches data from server.

Output is displayed in the layout "output". For this i use it like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.output);

TextView tvOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
tvOutput.setText("Data:");
//etc..
```

This layout also contains a button "BACK". When user presses this button i want it to go back to "main" layout. This is to allow user again to enter new details and fetch the output. But where does i write code for this button click handler ? For the "Submit" button in "main" layout, I write it in "onCreate()". But which place for the "BACK" button ?

Answer (score 0):

this code comes in the oncreate for the output layout. it will be onKeyDown if you are using the hardware back button. if you are using a button widget in that case you just need to write a onclicklistener for the button like you did for submit and call the intent there.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
           Intent i= new Intent(output.this,main.class);
           startActivity(i);
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: well in that case you'd have to write an onClickListener for that button which would come within the onCreate itself. but since every android device comes with a hardware back button, i would suggest you not use a back button widget. its an added redundancy to the UI design.
you can easily find the code to implement a click listener for button with a google search. i hope it helped.

Comment: i did mention, within the onCreate of the Activity.